# Вопросы, ответом подразумевающие список

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, модерация, учебные-материалы

Перебирал недавние вопросы и наткнулся на этот:

[Подскажите новичку где отрабатывать полученные знания Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419657/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-python)

Заметил, что он всё ещё не закрыт, и что в ответах к нему публикуются ссылки на ресурсы, позволяющие тренироваться не только на языке Python, поэтому потенциально полезные не только программистам на Python.

Вопрос следующий: имеет ли смысл создавать общий вопрос на эту тему, по аналогии с вопросами-списками книг:
[Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-python-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0),
[Книги по Java и другая литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-java-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0),
[Книги по C# и другая литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0),
или стоит закрывать подобные вопросы, как вопросы не по теме?

Заметил, что списки книг иногда опубликовывают в [описании соответствующей метки](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info), но пока существует тенденция создания именно общих вопросов с подобными списками.

Вопрос про отработку навыков программирования не кажется мне лишним или особо неуместным. В нём можно было бы собрать список ресурсов с краткими аннотациями содержимого и поддерживать его в актуальном состоянии.

Comment: Еще вот связанная тема про перечни IDE http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2059/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-ide/2072#2072

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько отличий между книгами и "ресурсами для тренировки":

1. Книги более долговечные. Сайты появляются и исчезают, ссылки умирают, а книги никуда не деваются, в худшем случае их становится сложнее найти.
2. У книг больше целевая аудитория. Как мне кажется, тех, кто читает книги, значительно больше, чем тем, кто тренируется на каких-то абстрактных задачках (сужу по своему окружению; да и оценки у QA намекают на такое положение вещей).

В результате списки с книгами, во-первых, более долговечны, и не так быстро устаревают; во-вторых, юзеров, способных поддерживать вопросы и ответы про книги в актуальном состоянии заметно больше, и тех, кому они пригодятся, тоже больше.

В целом, я с трудом верю в поддержание подобных QA в актуальном состоянии. Качество уже существующих ответов под вопросом — три из четырёх ресурсов с ходу требуют регистрации.

Comment: Какая гадость. Такие вопросы прямо запрещены на SO.com. Потому-что они полностью противоречат идее StackOverflow. В интернете и так есть миллион сайтов для разной субъективнщины, а но только SO дает хороших ответов на правильно поставленные вопросы.

Comment: Каждый ответ выражает характерное мнение его автора, и именно его решение оценивается баллами. Правки к списку оценить никак нельзя. Не понятно, какой критерий хорошести списка, и какие люди пришли к такому решению. Пожалуйста, давайте не будем засорять сайт непонятными списками.

Comment: @uhbif19 Вы о чём? Если о списках из этого вопроса, то они запрещены, о чём я и говорю. Если речь о списках книг, то сообщество решило их разрешить, хоть я и против. См. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/165